# Remove duplicates values from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json

I want to remove duplicates values from list which is inside the dictionary. I am trying to make configurable code to work on any field instead of making field specific.

**Input Data :**

```
{'Customer_Number': 90617174, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu', 'saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], 'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280, 12177218280]}]}
```

**Expected Output Data :**

```
{'Customer_Number': 90617174, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], 'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280]}]}
```

**code tried:**

```
dic = {'Customer_Number': 90617174, 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu', 'saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], 'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280, 12177218280]}]}

res = []
for i in dic:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
```

Comment: What you are trying right now is just adding the `dic` keys to the `res` list

Comment: @Mortz I am new to python and don't have much idea how to resolve this. I have just put what i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that you started with, you need to go a few levels deeper with that to find every such "repeating" list and dedupe it.

To dedupe, you can use a `set` - which is also a "container" data structure like a `list` but with some (many?) differences. You can get a good introduction to all of this in the [official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) -

```
for key in dic:
    if isinstance(dic[key], list):
        for inner_dict in dic[key]:
            for inner_key in inner_dict:
                if isinstance(inner_dict[inner_key], list):
                    inner_dict[inner_key] = list(set(inner_dict[inner_key]))

print(dic)
#{'Customer_Number': 90617174,
# 'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}],
# 'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280]}]}
```

Comment: You could make a recursive function or use visitor pattern to deep dive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()`

```py
import json 

dic = {
    'Customer_Number': 90617174,
    'Email': [
        {
            'Email_Type': 'Primary',
            'Email': list(set([
                'saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu',
                'saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu',
            ]))
        }
    ],
    'Phone_Number': [
        {
            'Phone_Type': 'Mobile',
            'Phone': list(set([
                12177218280,
                12177218280,
            ]))
        }
    ]
}

print(json.dumps(dic,indent=2))
```

If you want to do it on a list of `dic`'s then you can do like this:

```py
for dic in dics:
    for email in dic['Email']:
        email['Email'] = list(set(email['Email']))
    
    for phone in dic['Phone_Number']:
        phone['Phone'] = list(set(phone['Phone']))
```

Comment: I can't use the set inside the data. I have just given dic for the reference.

Comment: @mama Are you suggesting editing the data structure itself? I think that would become cumbersome very quickly

Comment: Nope I am just using the OP's own data to show him that 2 can become 1 with `set()` the more general implementation I will leave up to him self :)

Comment: @mama, your answer more specific to field. If you have 100 fields and same duplicate issue then it won't be effecitve ans.